# Unusual formatting of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I want to format the table of contents of a reader in a non-standard manner, see example:

[image]

In particular, the sections are listed 'inline', without page numbers, separated by bullets and indented w.r.t. the chapter listing. The unnumbered 'chapters' (bibliography, index, etc.) at the end of the document are aligned with the chapter numbers, not indented.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a transparent explanation of how to achieve this. A bit of searching got me to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163986/format-table-of-contents-with-latex?newreg=f44f6122b45c4879a7dffd07a5b6e014) on this site, which has an answer with a table of contents that looks somewhat similar to what I'm looking for, see the image below.

The problem is that the accompanying code is a **complete** mystery to me, I am unable to find any useful correlation between the code and the output. I hope someone here can either explain to me what the code does, or show me another way to get the look I want. Needless to say I'm a novice at TeX.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The manual to the `etoc` package has an example of something like this, if I  remember correctly

Comment: Also look at the [`titletoc`/`titlesec` documentaion](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

Comment: `etoc` is very powerful. If you are using `titlesec`, `titletoc` will cooperate with it. The best approach depends on minimal information about your document which we don't have. A minimal example would be helpful in this respect.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using [etoc package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{etoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\parindent=0pt
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
{\leavevmode\leftskip0em\relax}
{\etocifnumbered{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\etocnumber.}}{}%
\etocname\nobreak\hfill\nobreak
\rlap{\makebox[1.5em]{\etocpage}}\par}
{}
\etocsetstyle{section}
{\begingroup\leftskip1.5em\relax}
{\textbullet\hspace\itemsep%
\nolinebreak}
{\etocname\space}
{\par\endgroup}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
bye
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update (edited)**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{etoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\parindent=0pt
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
{\leavevmode\leftskip0em\relax}
{\etocifnumbered{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\etocnumber.}}{}%
\etocname\nobreak\hfill\nobreak
\rlap{\makebox[1.5em]{\etocpage}}\par}
{}
\etocsetstyle{section}
{\begingroup\leftskip1.5em\relax}
{\etociffirst{}{\textbullet\hspace\itemsep%
\nolinebreak}}
{\etocname\space}
{\par\endgroup}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
bye
\end{document}
```

Comment: alternatively you can use `\etociffirst{<do nothing>}{<put the bullet>}`.

Comment: @jfbu of course this is better.

Comment: @Servaes answer edited following jfbu's comment.

Comment: @Servaes Ok, sorry, i edited my answer again :-)